# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when capturing a GPU frame

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, crash, vbo

I was attempting to debug why I wasn't seeing a new object (quad) being rendered, so I used the "Capture GPU frame" feature of Xcode. It usually works fine, but now it's giving me `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in another render call, during `glDrawElements`.

Note that it *seems* similar to bugs I've seen, related to a mixed usage of VBOs and not. However, I'm definitely unbinding the VBO after usage, and disabling vertex attribute arrays:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(posAttr);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(texCoordAttr);
```

(Also, bear in mind that I'm only getting the crash when using "Capture GPU frame", not all the time)

What might I be doing wrong? Or could this be a bug in Xcode...?

Comment: Also, `glGetError()` isn't picking anything up.

Comment: Note I've eliminated VBOs as an issue: I converted my draw code to use no VBOs to be absolutely certain.

Comment: I've also fixed the reason why my original quad wasn't being rendered (I had a size param which was zero, all vertices were in the same place). However, this didn't fix the crash. Would be good to track it down still!

Comment: This could quite possibly be a result of trying to access data beyond the scope of VBO. It might be you will get the same crash if you use a release scheme instead of debug. Anyway this is way too little information to know anything for sure but I would start looking at your buffer data and the draw call sanity. Also possibility of losing scope by using multiple contexts or multithreading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed due to some GL state being left over, specifically a `glVertexAttribPointer`. The reason I didn't catch it was because it was an order of operations problem directly within the 3d engine itself: child objects were being iterated (and rendered) before some state was cleared up.

(Apologies, this was a tediously project-specific issue)